# Updating value on page from database using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am updating the database whenever a user clicks the like button. The update is successfully done but the problem is in updating the new fetched value from the database.

Control Function on which ajax is posting data :

```
public function plusrepo()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        $this->load->model('themodel');
        $rep['updated'] = $this->themodel->addrepo($this->input->post('resid'));
        echo $rep['updated'][0]." <span>Reputation</span>";
    }
}
```

This is how i am selecting from table and returning the result array.

```
$this->db->select('repo');
$this->db->from('restaurants');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$result = $this->db->get();
return $result->result_array();
```

My Ajax function on success does this :

```
success: function(){
         alert("Success");
         $(this).addClass('.up_arrow').removeClass('.up_arrowed');
         $('.rep_count').html(data);
         }
```

What is wrong? I'm confused.

Edited
This is the complete function for ajax

```
$('.up_arrow').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var resid = $(this).attr('name');

        var post_data = {
            'resid' : resid,
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        };

        if(resid){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/ci_theyaw/restaurants/plusrepo",
                data: post_data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    // alert(data);
                    // $(this).addClass('.up_arrow').removeClass('.up_arrowed');
                    // $('.rep_count').html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your current problem coming from your server side or your front end? Does the `.success` handler gets called (ie your `alert()` gets called)? Or does your controller `echo` the right data? It is best to isolate the problem.

Comment: No the alert is not getting called. The problem is i think on the server side.

Comment: How can i check what my controller just echoed?

Comment: If you are using Chrome you can open your console (F12 on Windows), go to Network tab, and see the request/response. Click on your response which will show up as soon as you click the button that initiates AJAX call, and check the 'Preview'

Comment: I did that and i'm getting an error right there

`POST http://localhost/ci_theyaw/restaurants/plusrepo  jquery.js:8526
send jquery.js:8526
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7978
(anonymous function) restaurants:456
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3074
elemData.handle`

Comment: You said your POST update successfully, so it successfully update your record in your database when you click on the button?

Comment: yes the database gets updated but the value of likes fetched after the update is not getting into that div

Comment: The problem is that my xhr.status is returning 0 which means that the responseText is empty.

Comment: Could you tell us the response code from AJAX call?

Comment: Try altering the php section as i did and also alerting the `data` obtained. Also try alerting `resid`. also are you obtaining the `$id` in the php code? it maybe breaking the entire php side.

Comment: @JofryHS All i'm getting is a 0

Comment: Even if the response text is 0, your server must return a response code (400, 203, etc..)

Comment: Nopes. I'm not getting anything else. Just a 0 and an error in the console and a blank alert for thrownError.

Comment: I have come across a ajax tutorial.
This may be helpful http://www.techrecite.com/how-to-update-page-data-from-database-using-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass data to success function like this :

```
success: function(data){
```

So full ajax success callback function would be :

```
success: function(data){
     alert("Success");
     $(this).addClass('.up_arrow').removeClass('.up_arrowed');
     $('.rep_count').html(data);
}
```

Also :

```
$this->db->select('repo');
$this->db->from('restaurants');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->limit(1);
$result = $this->db->get();
print_r($result);//For testing
//echo $result['repo']; // For working code
```

Comment: did this still no luck?

Comment: what do you get while `alert(data);` ?

Comment: The error part of my ajax function is returning the `alert(xhr.status)` or `alert(thrownError)` as 0.

Comment: @Cruze : Try altering the php section as i did and also alerting the `data` obtained. Also try alerting `resid`

Comment: The problem is that success function is not getting executed and every time the xhr.status returns 0 which is in the error function. I think the server is not able to generate the response which it should.

Answer (score 1):

Change,

```
$this->db->select('repo');
$this->db->from('restaurants');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$result = $this->db->get();
return $result->result_array();
```

To,

```
$this->db->select('repo');
$this->db->from('restaurants');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$result = $this->db->get();
$row=$result->result_array();
return $row['repo'];
```

And,

```
     success: function(){
       alert("Success");
       $(this).addClass('.up_arrow').removeClass('.up_arrowed');
       $('.rep_count').html(data);
     }
```

To,

```
     success: function(data){
       alert("Success");
       $(this).addClass('.up_arrow').removeClass('.up_arrowed');
       $('.rep_count').html(data);
     }
```

Here you forgot to pass **data** to success function.

Comment: I think this will return what i need but still no luck with the updating on page.

Comment: Yes noticed that but still the error part of my ajax is returning 0 as xhr.status / thrownerror

Comment: Try to log your data to console using console.log(data) from success function. What is the output?

Comment: `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }`

Comment: This handles the error.. so i'm just getting 0 as an alert. Success part isnt executing.

Comment: Ok, can you post the full javascript function in question? The parts before success function also.

Comment: The problem is that my xhr.status is returning 0 which means that the responseText is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->db->select('repo');
$this->db->from('restaurants');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$result = $this->db->get()->row_array();
return $result['repo'];

echo $rep['updated']." <span>Reputation</span>";
```

Change :

```
url: "<?=base_url('restaurants/plusrepo')?>",
```

Comment: Edited the above answer try once changing it